# Javascript moment - timezone, difference between dates in different time zones

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, difference, gmt

I have:

```
var now = moment.format(); //get current time
var days = 5; //days I need to subtract from time(then)
var then = '05/02/2016 12:00 am';
```

Now I need to get difference between `now` and `then` substract(-) 5 days but in +0000 so GMT +0.
so `now` must be in user localtime and `then` must be at +0000 GMT.

How I can get difference between this dates in days, hours, minutes, seconds?

I try:

```
var now  = moment().format();                         
var then = moment('05/02/2016 12:00 am').utcOffset(+0000).format(); 
    then = moment(then).subtract(5,'days');
    d = moment.utc(moment(now).diff(moment(then))).format("DD HH:mm:ss");
```

but I get result- which is wrong...

```
"27 18:48:55"
```

Comment: is that May 2nd, or Feb 5th?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: expected result will be difference in days, hours,minutes between now() and 27. April (becouse 2.May - 5 days = 27. April)

Comment: So, is it the case that you want the time now, in local, and the time five days ago, but in utc? I don't see how the duration matters in this. Those two things will always be five days apart. Can you clarify this a little bit?

Comment: I solve this maybe in best way but work: var tz = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60*(-1);
    var now  = moment.utc();
    var dod = parseInt('{{$article->auction_end}}')-1;
    var then = moment.utc(obj.start).utcOffset(+0000).subtract(dod, 'days');
    then = moment(then).add(tz,'hours');
    var duration = moment.duration(then.diff(now));
    d = duration.days()+'d '+duration.hours()+'h '+duration.minutes()+'m '+duration.seconds();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use a time difference as a time. You need to use `moment.duration()` with the return value of the `diff`. You should also call `then.diff(now)` to get a positive difference. There were also some unnecessary calls to `.format()` and `moment()` that I removed.

```
var now  = moment();
var then = moment('05/02/2016 12:00 am').utcOffset(+0000).subtract(5, 'days');
var duration = moment.duration(then.diff(now));
console.log(duration.days(), duration.hours(), duration.minutes(), duration.seconds());
```

logs

```
4 3 15 46
```

Comment: I think that was a problem, thanks very much for help

Comment: hm, there is a problem now with GMT... becouse someone from Dubaigmt +4 and someone from Europe dont get the same difference

Comment: I create auction and auction must end at same time for each timezone, so user from Asia must get (4h 33m) but also someone from Europe must get (4h 33m) and someone from US must get (4h 33m) ... BECOUSE OF THAT I NEED TO GET +0 time and calculate difference becouse +0 time is everywhere the same.

Comment: @Andrew I think instead of `moment('05/02/2016 12:00 am').utcOffset(+0000)`, you want `moment.utc('05/02/2016 12:00 am')`.

Comment: You need to specify a format as well. You are falling back to JS date construction right now, and you should be receiving a deprecation warning. This is not what you want, and it may cause unpredictable results.

Comment: how, please wrie wxampe

Comment: Now when someone look with Dubai timezone they have 0d 3h 50m, and when look someone from Europe then get 0d 5h 50m ... How to solve this? Any ideas ?

Comment: I can write a longer response to this later, but you need to read the parsing guide on moment's website: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/