# MomentJS and days difference

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, datediff

My timezone is GMT+2.
When local time '2020-05-21 01:00' 
that should mean '2020-05-20 23:00' in UTC time zone (GMT+0)

So days difference should say: 1
This code deosnt give that result. Anyone have idea why ?

EDIT: Simply said: Saturday 1am in my place is Friday 11pm in UTC. so there SHOULD be 1 day difference. Here is live code sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-playground-vteexd?embed=1&file=index.ts

Comment: Please post the code here. *diff* truncates the decimal part, so if the difference is less than 1 the result is 0.

Comment: Getting the timestamp value reveals that they are the same date, internally. It is true that `.diff()` accepts a third Boolean parameter, to output decimals, but the result is still 0.

Comment: code is in stackblitz

Comment: BTW,  the difference between 2020-05-21 01:00 +02:00 and 2020-05-20 23:00 Z is zero, they are the same instant in time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue was caused by a misunderstanding of dates and the *diff* function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm going to give solution to my own question:

```
 import moment from "moment-timezone";

//test for GMT+1
var now = moment().startOf("day").add(1, "hours");
console.log(now.format(), " now", now.format('dddd'));

let res= GetDayOffsetUTC(now);
console.log("Day diff: ", res);

// Get DAY difference between local and UTC time
// Responses:
// -1 : your local time is 1 day ahead of UTC
//  1 : your local time is 1 day after UTC
//  0 : your local time is same day as UTC



   function GetDayOffsetUTC(date) {
      const utcOffset = date.utcOffset();

      const utc = date.clone().add(-utcOffset, "minutes");

      const dayDiff = utc.startOf("day").diff(date.startOf("day"), "days");
      return dayDiff;
    }
```

Comment: You can do this much more simply by comparing the local and UTC dates in the same format (say ISO 8601) and if they're different, the difference is 1 day. Or you can see if the local time of day is less than the offset from midnight (which is what you're actually detecting).

Answer (score 1):

Internally they are the same date. To prove that, try comparing their timestamps `now.format('X')` === `utc.format('X')`.

As a solution, I would propose using [moment durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to measure the time difference, and using `.days()` to get the desired value.

[This could be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797014/javascript-moment-timezone-difference-between-dates-in-different-time-zones).

Comment: that gives idea , but no solution.
Simply said: Saturday 1am in my place is Friday 11pm in UTC. so there SHOULD be 1 day difference. How to calculate that ?

Comment: @Jalle—that is an unconventional interpretation of date differences. They are the same instant in time, so how can they be 1 day different? Date objects are just a time value, if a date *d* represented in some timezone is the day prior to the same date represented in a different timezone, you want `d - d === 1 day`. Can yo see the issues with that? Note that date instances do not have any timezone information associated with them, they're just a time value.

Comment: check my answer